# Subscription to the NgRx store returns empty object

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, state-management

I am trying to develop a a simple angular app using `NgRx` to maintain state.

Unfortunately, the callback to the subscription to the store gets fired but always returns an empty object.

I am trying to dispatch the object to store as

```
this._store.dispatch({
  type: 'ShowPassword',
  payload: value
})
```

and a look at the reducer function

```
export function showPasswordReducer(state, action) {
  //console.log(state);
    switch (action.type) {

    case 'ShowPassword':
      return {
        ...state,
        'ShowPassword': action.payload
      }
    break;
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

I am adding the reference of `StoreModule` in the imports array of root module as

```
StoreModule.forRoot(showPasswordReducer)
```

and subscribing to the store as

```
this._store.subscribe(val => {
    if (val)
        this.showPassword = val.ShowPassword;
})
```

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-first-ngrx-demo

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. It is definitely not off topic and a genuine problem to which I seek solution.

Comment: You probably got a downvote because this does not present a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @AJT_82 yes but I do have a working stackblitz

Comment: Always put at least some relevant code in your question.

Comment: Yes, but the emphasis being ... **in the question itself** Stackblitz should be just an addition. BTW, it's **great** that you have a stackblitz, but the question becomes useless if (when...) the link dies.

Comment: To all the down-voters, I have added all the necessary details to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of basic NGRX pieces missing in your code -

Let's deal with them one by one:

a) You must have an initial state [I am assuming that you want to have a state which tracks a boolean called `showPassword`]. Define an initial state object like this:

```
export const initialState = {
  showPassword: false
};
```

b) Setup your reducer to make use of initial state like this:

```
export function showPasswordReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  //console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ShowPassword':
      return {showPassword: action.payload};
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Notice that in case of default action reducer will return the initial state.

c) Now inject the reducer in `forRoot` method with the state name like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, StoreModule.forRoot({ShowPassword: showPasswordReducer})],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

d) Now subscribe to the store [**Ideally You MUST have selectors** to get the piece of information from the store but to keep things simple, simply subscribe to the store directly and look for the same property which was used in the `forRoot` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._store.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
      if (val)
        this.showPassword = val.ShowPassword.showPassword;
    })
  }
```

Working stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-first-ngrx-demo-7yrl2r?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are using ngrx 8, so you should embrace that syntax, which is also cleaner in my opinion. We now have access to `createReducer` and `createAction`. So I suggest the following:

```ts
import { createAction, createReducer, on, } from '@ngrx/store';

export const showPwd = createAction(
  'Show Password',
  ({ showPw }: { showPw: boolean }) => ({
    showPw,
  })
)

const initialState = {
  showPw: false
};

export const showPasswordReducer = createReducer(
  initialState.showPw,
    // here you would probably want to have the action(s) in a separate file
    on(this.showPwd, (state: any, action: any) => {
    return action.showPw;
  }),
)

export function reducer(state: any | undefined, action: any) {
  return showPasswordReducer(state, action);
}
```

Then remember to mark to app.module `imports`:

```ts
StoreModule.forRoot({showPwd: showPasswordReducer})
```

Then finally in the component where you dispatch the action and listen to store:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this._store.subscribe(val => {
    if (val && val.showPwd)
      this.showPassword = val.showPwd;
  })
}

ToggleCheckbox(value: boolean) {
  this._store.dispatch(showPwd({showPw: value}))
}
```

**Your forked [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-first-ngrx-demo-g9rkps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. I'll definitely try the new syntax.